# SKLearn cross_val_score error AttributeError("'Binarizer' object has no attribute 'predict'",)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I have this code

```
        try:
            estimator = make_pipeline(*steps)
            mean_scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X_full.values, y_full.values,
                                          scoring='f1_macro',
                                          cv=5)
        except Exception as e:
            print('EXCEPTION: ', str(e))
            print('Could not execute ', strings)
```

and here is steps

```
steps
[MissingIndicator(err...se='auto'), SimpleImputer(copy=T...verbose=0), Binarizer(copy=True,...shold=0.0)]
0:MissingIndicator(error_on_new=True, features='missing-only',
         missing_values=nan, sparse='auto')
1:SimpleImputer(copy=True, fill_value=None, missing_values=nan, strategy='mean',
       verbose=0)
2:Binarizer(copy=True, threshold=0.0)
__len__:3
```

X_full and y_full are just 1 column each. The steps are just SKLearn primitives. So estimator has a predict attribute and when I check it I see the error

```
AttributeError("'Binarizer' object has no attribute 'predict'",)
```

I'm not really sure what is going on cause `make_pipeline` and `cross_val_score` are SKLearn functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Binarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Binarizer.html) (and hence your pipeline) is a transformer, not a predictor.  You can call `estimator.transform` (after fitting), but not `estimator.predict` or `estimator.predict_proba`, and hence scoring fails.